# Why can't I access the context's methods or properties

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

I am trying to use React's context api to manage a global state.  When I try to invoke contextual methods or access contextual proprties, I get errors saying "this.context.setUser function does not exist" or "undefined".

I have however been able to hard code values into the state of the context and retreive the hardcoded value.

Feed Context

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    const FeedContext = React.createContext({
      Feed: [],
      user: '',
      error: null,
      setError: () => {},
      clearError: () => {},
      setFeed: () => {},
      setUser: () => {}
    })

     export default FeedContext

    export class FeedProvider extends Component {
      state = {
        feed: [],
        error: null,
        user: ''
      };

      setUser = user => {
        this.setState({ user })
      }

      setFeed = Feed => {
        this.setState({ Feed })
      }

      setError = error => {

        console.error()
        this.setState({ error })
      }

      clearError = () => {
        console.log('context is accessed')
        this.setState({ error: null })
      }

      render() {
        const value = {
          feed: this.state.feed,
          error: this.state.error,
          setError: this.setError,
          clearError: this.clearError,
          setFeed: this.setFeed,
          setUser: this.setUser
        }

        return (
          <FeedContext.Provider value={value}>
            {this.props.children}
          </FeedContext.Provider>
        )
      }
    }
```

AccountPanel.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import FeedContext from "../../contexts/FeedContext";

    // functional component
    class AccountPanel extends React.Component {


    static contextType = FeedContext


    renderUserInfo(){
        const { user = [] } = this.context;

        //this returns "undefined"
        console.log(user.user)

        //this returns "user.setUser() is not a function"
        user.setUser('newUser')

        //this returns ' '
        this.context.setUser('y')
        console.log(user)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <section>
                { this.renderUserInfo() }
               AccountPanel
            </section>
        )
       }

    }

    export default AccountPanel;
```

I would like to be able to update the contextual state/user via this.context.setUser('newUser), then consume that value in my navbar component

Comment: My best guess is `AccountPanel` is *not* wrapped by a context provider. Can you share the code that renders `AccountPanel` and the provider?

Comment: Another guess is that the static property is not properly compiled. Can you check that you have `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` in your `.babelrc` plugins?

Comment: @Matthieu Account panel.js (second snippett) and the provider is ereturned from FeedContext at the bottom of the snippett. This code actually came from a course I'm taking, and I'm trying to implement the pattern they used.  But it isnt how I normally see it implemented.

Comment: I meant that some part of your app should `import { FeedProvider }` and use it. `AccountPanel` should be under `FeedProvider` in the app's hierarchy.

Comment: While we're at it: It seems `user: this.state.user,` is missing from the context provider's value.

Comment: Not sure how to check my babel plugins, but I dont see babel anywhere in my package.json, if that helps.

Comment: Ive added 
    user: this.state.user,
and It still returns undefined

Comment: You can check that the issue comes from [this package](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) being missing, as explained by [the doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype), by doing `AccountPanel.contextType = FeedContext` instead of using a static property

Comment: Well I know that     
     static contextType = FeedContext     
works because      
     console.log(this.context)
returns an object containing all of the contextual properties, but I cant access them via the normal context.value method...

Answer (score -1):

File App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AccountPanel from "./components/AccountPanel";
import { FeedProvider } from './components/FeedContext';


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <FeedProvider>
          <AccountPanel />
      </FeedProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

File : FeedContext.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const FeedContext = React.createContext({
  Feed: [],
  user: '',
  error: null,
  setError: () => {},
  clearError: () => {},
  setFeed: () => {},
  setUser: () => {}
})

export default FeedContext

export class FeedProvider extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      feed: [],
      error: null,
      user: "11"
    };
  }


  setUser = user => {
    console.log(`setting usr fns called for username: ${user}`);
    this.setState({ user });
  }

  setFeed = Feed => {
    this.setState({ Feed })
  }

  setError = error => {

    console.error()
    this.setState({ error })
  }

  clearError = () => {
    console.log('context is accessed')
    this.setState({ error: null })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('FeedProvider:componentDidMount');
  }

  render() {
    let value1 = {

      Feed:this.state.feed,
      user:this.state.user,
      error:this.state.error,
      setError:this.setError,
      clearError:this.clearError,
      setFeed:this.setFeed,
      setUser:this.setUser
    }

    return (
      <FeedContext.Provider value={value1}>
        {this.props.children}
      </FeedContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

File : AccountPanel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FeedContext from "./FeedContext";

    // functional component
    class AccountPanel extends React.Component {


    static contextType = FeedContext
    // return BlogPost component html/(JSX)

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('AccountPanel:componentDidMount');
        console.log(this.context);
        const  value  = this.context;

        //this returns "undefined"
        console.log(value.user)

        //this returns "user.setUser() is not a function"
        console.log(value.setUser);
        value.setUser('newUser');
    }


    render(){
        const  value  = this.context;
        console.log(`Value of new User is : ${value.user}`);
        return (
            <section>
               AccountPanel
            </section>
        )
       }

    }

    export default AccountPanel;
```

Hope This helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have already been able to retrieve hardcoded data from the context...I need to be able to use context.setUser() to update the user property and then rerieve it...and this can be acheived without the props being passed in from a parent...

Comment: the data is hardcoded I know but it gets overridden once the set user is called.

Comment: why don't you at least provide an explanation of what went wrong instead of posting whole solution.